# need help translating mysql query to postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm messing around with a tutorial
http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-01-18/get_rolling_with_kendo_ui_and_php_ndash_part_1.aspx

and using the postgres northwind port from here:
  http://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=northwind.postgre.sql

I cannot get this query to execute on the db:

```
SELECT TRIM(t.TerritoryDescription) AS TerritoryDescription
            FROM Territories t                 
            INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID    
            INNER JOIN Employees e ON et.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID           
            WHERE e.EmployeeID = 1
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  column t.territoryid does not exist
LINE 3:             INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories et ON t.Territory
```

but the table `territories` and the `territoryid` column are both there.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: updated the question with the error

Comment: Case sensitive column names maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the SQL that you have used to create the database, you are using quoted column names:

```
CREATE TABLE territories (
    "TerritoryID" character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    "TerritoryDescription" bpchar NOT NULL,
    "RegionID" smallint NOT NULL
);
```

Since you used quoted names, postgres expects the column case to match. However it will by default lowercase all column names:

> PostgreSQL automatically folds all identifiers (e.g. table/column
>   names) to lower-case values at object creation time and at query time.
>   To force the use of mixed or upper case identifiers, you must escape
>   the identifier using double quotes ("").

*From the [PHP pgsql documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php).*

So, quote your column names in `""` when you execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Adrian Cornish,
It was the case-sensitivity, so this works now:

```
SELECT TRIM(t."TerritoryDescription") AS "TerritoryDescription"
        FROM Territories t                 
        INNER JOIN employeeterritories et ON t."TerritoryID" = et."TerritoryID"    
        INNER JOIN employees e ON et."EmployeeID" = e."EmployeeID"           
        WHERE e."EmployeeID" = 1
```